# Unable to focus JOptionPane on foreground with default frame

Tags: java, swing, focus, awt

I have a piece of code in my program where in I need to display an error message. Code:

```
String ErrorMsg=" Error to be Diplayed ";
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ErrorMsg, "Failure", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

Note: Default frame is used.

The message is successfully displayed, but before acknowledging by pressing "OK" button if I try any other successful flow the message box control is lost and message box won't be on foreground blocking even the successive flows.

**I want the Message Box to be on the foreground always** until the user presses "OK" button, rather losing focus and getting hidden. How to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by 'default frame'?  That should be the component passed to `showMessageDialog` instead of `null`.

Comment: I am not using any component[frame] , so the field would be null.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : My program is not an AWT/Swing application, i just need to display just one error so there is no usage of frame as such.

Comment: @ShaikMd: if you want GUI behavior, then make it a GUI. Else what you see is what you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code is enough to make a JoptionPane message with default frame to be set on top .

```
        JDialog dialog = new JOptionPane("ErrorMsg",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE,JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION).createDialog(" Failure"); 
        dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        dialog.dispose();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want JOptionPane to behave as it would in a full-fledged GUI, then first create a full-fledged Swing GUI. Forget using "default" frames or whatever you're using (the console perhaps). You are desiring GUI behavior, and so to get this you must create a GUI by displaying your application in a JFrame and have the JFrame launch the JOptionPane.

Answer (score 2):

Pass reference to the parent frame instead of the null (first param).

Comment: You have the "Default frame is used." Pass the reference to the JOptionPane.

Comment: @StanislavL: I think he's calling the console a "default frame". 1+ though for trying to help with this very confusing question.

Answer (score 2):

> I want the Message Box to be on the foreground always until the user presses "OK" button, rather losing focus and getting hidden.

Use a JFrame and `setAlwaysOnTop(true)`. You will need to display your own message and button.

A JOptionPane uses a JDialog behind the scenes. A JDialog does not support this property.

Edit:

To get the icon used by the option pane you can use:

```
Icon icon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon");
```

For a list of the other icons see: [UIManager Defaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/).

Comment: I followed the same steps , but how to display error symbol ?

Comment: I created a Jframe ,used JLabel and Jbutton made it appear on the foreground ,disabled min,max option in the titlebar...in short made it look like a Dialog box ...Now i want to display "X" error symbol in it just like the dialog box in error case ...how to do it ? i extending from Jdialog class ..